# Comment formuler une traduction de « scroll down (to) » transitif/intransitif etc. ?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, prépositions, formulation-idiomatique, informatique

Le contexte c'est le mode d'emploi applicatif, d'une application surtout utilisée sur des postes de travail :

> *Scroll down, check the details...
>
> Scroll down to the X section, check
> the details...*

Comment motiver la formulation après avoir répondu aux/pris en considération les questions suivantes :

1. S'agit-il de [*défiler*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8393068/defiler-vers-le-bas), *faire défiler* ou *descendre* ; lequel préfère-t-on
   et pourquoi ?
2. A-t-on besoin de dire « dans l'écran » ou « vers le bas », surtout dans la première
   formulation et pourquoi ?
3. Quelle préposition est-il préférable d'employer dans la seconde
   formulation surtout, et pourquoi : *à, jusqu'à, dans, vers* ?
4. Peut-on aussi employer « page » plutôt qu'écran même s'il ne s'agit
   pas d'une page/application web ?

Answer (score 5):

Le verbe scroller est maintenant bien implanté en France donc l'expression la plus courante doit être ***scroller vers le bas** (jusqu'à la section/au paragraphe [...])*.

Sinon, ***faire défiler (la page) vers le bas*** me semble l'expression la plus idiomatique.

Si on souhaite éviter de parler de page et de défilement, on peut simplement dire ***voir plus loin***, ***plus bas*** ou ***ci-dessous***.

Answer (score 4):

Si j'écrivais pour mes coéquipiers, je traduirais:

> Déroulez, vérifiez les détails...
> Déroulez jusqu'à la section X, vérifiez les détails...

Par exemple, "scroll-down list" se traduit par *liste déroulante*; *scrollez* ou *liste scrollable* sont compris partout et peuvent être soit acceptés, soit rejetés comme franglish, selon les usage locaux.

*Défilez* au sens de *Déroulez* avec un COD collectif ou en l'absence de COD me semble un anglicisme sorti d'un outil de traduction automatique; ma génération préfère *Faites défiler*. On *défile des perles*, pas *un rosaire* et, si *on défile* tout court, *on* est soldat ou majorette.

Dans toutes ces phrases, il est inutile de traduire "down", qui est plus un mot-outil qu'un adverbe de lieu: par entente tacite avec mes lecteurs, tout texte se déroule dans le sens de lecture depuis l'époque des parchemins. Par contre, "move the pointer to scroll up and down" se traduit *Déplacez le pointeur pour (faire) défiler {verticalement|vers le haut ou (vers) le bas.}*.

Quant au choix de la proposition: *jusqu'à* est la traduction exacte. *{À|au début de|dans|au milieu de} la section X* demandent un verbe tel que *placez-vous*, insistant sur le point d'atterrissage plus que sur le mouvement qui y mène; tandis que *Déroulez vers la section X* traduirait "Scroll toward section X" et, sans autre précision, implique que la section n'est pas atteinte.

Enfin, la chose {scrollée|déroulée} est exactement celle du texte anglais: page, écran, éditeur, liste, composant de dialogue, message, texte, zone de saisie, zone d'affichage, fenêtre, bandeau, menu, que sais-je. Aucuns de ces termes ne sont exactement interchangeables; si le texte anglais entretient l'ambiguïté, la langue française permet et la sagesse commande, à mon avis, d'en faire autant.

Comment: @ninja米étoilé Certes, je crois que mon commentaire devrait plutôt être une proposition d'édition. Il ne s'agit pas d'une variante, simplement d'une autre tournure de phrase. La traduction de "to scroll", donc la réponse, reste identique.

Comment: Face à une autre _tournure de phrase_, mon commentaire demeure.